# React-navigation default drawer icon, how to change it?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

How can I change the icon point in the image below? I have not been able to find the documentation in the docs, I would like to change it to a different icon but I have no idea how to do this.

I found documentation about [drawerIcon](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#drawericon) but as far as I know and manage to implement that icon is for the menu items in the drawer it self not for the screen header.

[image]

Here is my code:

```js
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const headerOptions = {
  title: 'Task List',
  drawerIcon: ({ focused, size, color }) => <Ionicons name="ios-pizza" color="red" size={24} />,
};

const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }, props) => {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator screenOptions={{ drawerType: 'front' }}>
      <Drawer.Screen name="TaskList" component={TaskListScreen} options={headerOptions} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="TaskView" component={TaskViewScreen} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Notifications" component={Notifications} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
};
```

But as mention before it renders the icons in the drawer item as shown below
[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> `headerLeft`: Function which returns a React Element to display on the left side of the header. You can use it to implement your custom left button, for example:

```js
<Drawer.Navigator
  screenOptions={({ navigation }) => ({
    headerLeft: props => <IconComponent onPress={navigation.toggleDrawer} />,
  })}
>
  ...
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

Comment: Please remove the (Untested) flag if this did work for you

Comment: I found about `headerLeft` in an example code from their documentation, the problem with this approach is that I have to do the same for every drawer navigator item, I wonder if there is a global solution?

Comment: The code I included in the answer above is a global solution

Comment: You are correct, I was applying the options to the Screen rather than the Navigation, my bad and thank you

Comment: If the above code works fine, please remove the untested flag (or tell me to remove it). Also, you can click the checkmark (✓) to accept it. That way others know that you've been (sufficiently) helped.

Answer (score 2):

you can also use a **image** as a drawer icon.

```
screenOptions={({ navigation }) => ({
  headerLeft: () =>
     <Pressable onPress={navigation.toggleDrawer}>
       <Text>
          <Avatar.Image size={32} source={{ uri: deafaultImage }} />
       </Text>
      </Pressable >
     })}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<Drawer.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
        headerTintColor: 'red', // -----> by changing color from here
    }} drawerContent={props => <DrawerContent {...props} />} >
    <Drawer.Screen />
</Drawer.Navigator >
```